# Magento 2 email Template issue

Tags: magento2

I am having an issue when I send an email from Magento 2 backend getting an error message :

This is a message in Mime Format. If you see this, your mail reader does not support this format. --=_5c30b6d595a8b80bb6a83b244f4a6175 Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8 Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

I have attached my code can you please help me how can resolve the issue

Thanks!

```
<pre>
{{template config_path="design/email/header_template"}}
<table>
    <tr class="email-intro">
        <td>
            <p class="greeting">{{trans "%name," name=$order_data.customer_name}}</p>
            <p>
                {{trans "Muchas gracias por su pedido en %store_name." store_name=$store.frontend_name}}
                {{trans 'You can check the status of your order by <a href="%account_url">logging into your account</a>.' account_url=$this.getUrl($store,'customer/account/',[_nosid:1]) |raw}}
               
            </p>
        </td>
    </tr>
     <tr class="email-summary">
        <td>
            <p>{{trans "Adjuntamos la factura #%invoice_id para su pedido #%order_id" invoice_id=$invoice.increment_id order_id=$order.increment_id}}</p>
        </td>
    </tr>
            {{layout area="frontend" handle="sales_email_order_invoice_items" invoice_id=$invoice_id order_id=$order_id}}
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<p>Una vez que el paquete sea enviado te enviaremos un número de seguimiento. Puede comprobar el estado de su pedido accediendo a su cuenta.</p>
<p>{{trans 'If you have questions about your order, you can email us at <a href="mailto:%store_email">%store_email</a>' store_email=$store_email |raw}}{{depend store_phone}} {{trans 'or call us at <a href="tel:%store_phone">%store_phone</a>' store_phone=$store_phone |raw}}{{/depend}}.
                {{depend store_hours}}
                    {{trans 'Our hours are <span class="no-link">%store_hours</span>.' store_hours=$store_hours |raw}}
                {{/depend}}
<p>Atentamente,<br>
¡Tu Equipo de Oktohealth!</p>
</pre>
```

Answer (score 1):

As workaround you can put the following after $mail->setBody($message);

$mail->headers()->get('content-type')->setType('multipart/alternative')

This issue is also reflected here. You can find more answers here: https://github.com/zendframework/zendframework/issues/2460